# How to only allow certain entries in a list?

Tags: python

I want to allow the user to only be able enter a list consisting of 0 and 1 in a function.

e.g function(1,0,1,0) like binary, but if e.g function(2,0,2,1) is entered it gives an error.

Comment: [No code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. What have you already tried, and what do you need help with exactly? There are at least three separate parts to this: iterate through the arguments, check their value, and raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would instead just pass a list into the function. But if you want a function to be able to take in a variable number of elements as non-keyword arguments, you could use *args:

```py
def function(*args):
    for arg in args:
        if arg not in [0, 1]:
            raise ValueError
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class NonBinaryError(Exception):
    pass


def binary(*args):
    for i in args:
        if i not in [0, 1]:
            raise NonBinaryError
    print('Hey, this is binary!')

binary(1, 0, 0, 1, 1) -> Hey, this is binary!
binary(1, 0, 3, 1, 1) -> __main__.NonBinaryError
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this might be to raise an exception in your function if the arguments inserted are not 0 or 1.
Consider the following:

```
def allBinary(List):
     for (k in list): 
        if (k!=0 or k!=1): return False
     return True
```

Then in your function declaration:

```
def function(List):
    if not allBinary(List): raise Exception("Accepts only binary numbers")
    ...
```